# How to use dlib in Xcode C++ console application

Tags: c++, xcode, build, compiler-errors, dlib

I have installed dlib using Homebrew.

```
brew install dlib
```

How can I create a C++ project that uses dlib in Xcode ? I have tried some build settings. However, it does not work.

- Add `/usr/local/Cellar/dlib/19.1_2/include` to **Header Search Paths**
- Add `/usr/local/Cellar/dlib/19.1_2/lib` to **Library Search Paths**
- Add `-ldlib` to **Other Linker Flags**

I have got these errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_cblas_dgemm", referenced from:
  dlib::blas_bindings::cblas_gemm(dlib::blas_bindings::CBLAS_ORDER, dlib::blas_bindings::CBLAS_TRANSPOSE, dlib::blas_bindings::CBLAS_TRANSPOSE, int, int, int, double, double const*, int, double const*, int, double, double*, int) in main.o
"_cblas_saxpy", referenced from:
  dlib::blas_bindings::cblas_axpy(int, float, float const*, int, float*, int) in main.o
"_cblas_sscal", referenced from:
  dlib::blas_bindings::cblas_scal(int, float, float*) in main.o
"_dgesvd_", referenced from:
  dlib::lapack::binding::gesvd(char, char, int, int, double*, int, double*, double*, int, double*, int, double*, int) in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: did you tried compiling it from sourcecode?

Comment: @Evgeniy Yes, I tried. I got the same result. I have found that dlib is trying to access BLAS while compiling my program. It is provided in Accelerate.framework on macOS. After adding that framework to project, the problem has been solved.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I am trying to compile through the command line with cmake, though. You wouldn't know how to add this to the cmake files, would you?

Comment: First, you need to find out where Accelerate.framework is. Then, you can add it to the cmake files. However, I don't know how to add it. I am not quite familiar with cmake. Alternatively, you may use OpenBLAS library. However, I have never tried it.

Comment: @fivetech so, have you solved that issue? If yes, could you write little guide, please?

Comment: I have added answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, homebrew installs dlib without any BLAS library. I have solved the issue by linking **Accelerate.framework** with binary file.

**Accelarate.framework** is provided by Apple. It includes everything that dlib needs. Further information:
https://developer.apple.com/reference/accelerate

In order to add that library to your project,

1. Choose the project name in project navigator (Left Side).
2. If it is not appeared on the editor, click **"Show project and targets list"** and choose target binary.

   [image]
3. Choose "Build Phases" shown below.
   [image]
4. Expand **"Link Binary With Libraries"** and click add items icon.
5. Search **Accelerate.framework** and add it.
6. Change its status to "Required".

---

Alternatively, it may work if you uninstall dlib and install dlib with `brew install dlib --with-openblas` command. However, I haven't tested it yet.

By the way, Homebrew warns about openblas if you `brew info openblas`:

> macOS already provides this software and installing another version in
>   parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

```
brew cask install xquartz
brew install gtk+3 boost
brew install dlib
```

Then your setup will be fine. I am using without adding `Accelerate.framework` explicitly.